# Minimal k-subset intersection

Tags: set, code-coverage, gcov, np, np-hard

Given n subsets (T1, T2... Tn) s.t. each subset has elements from [1 to p] (where p may or may not be given). The user can specify any k (s.t. k<=n) and I need to find k such subsets out of these n, such that the intersection of subsets Ta1, Ta2, ... Tak yields minimum cardinality. Ta1 ∩ Ta2 ∩ ... Tak has minimum possible numbers.

Original problem: Finding k test cases out of n randomly generated test cases that yield line coverage closest to that of n test cases on any code. Used gcov to determine which test case are unable to cover which lines.

Say: a program has 6 lines (for simplicity) and we run 3 tests on it. After running test 1, T1={1,2,3}, i.e., line no 1-3 didn't get covered/executed after test 1 has finished. We separately run tests 2 and 3 to get T2={4,5,6} and T3={2,4}. Now user can mention any value of k for which we have to give k out of n test cases which have closest coverage to all the test cases.

When we run T1 and T2 together, T1 covers 4,5,6 but not 1,2,3 and T2 covers 1,2,3 but not 4,5,6. Hence T1 and T2 cover 1,2,3,4,5,6 and nothing is left uncovered at least once. T1 ∩ T2 and thus T1 ∩ T2 ∩ T3, both yields ∅.

Now, for k=1, best answer is: T3 (cardinality = 2),
for k=2, best answer is: T1 and T2 since T1 ∩ T2 yields ∅ (as it covers all). Finally for k=3, choose all T1, T2 and T3, as intersection would be ∅ (zero cardinality)

Comment: a1, a2, ..., ak and 1, 2, 3, ... n (general i) represent test cases while Ta1, Ta2, ..., T1, T2, ..., Tn (general Ti). Here Ti represent sets of line numbers (of code) that were not executed while coverage was tested for test case no. i. Please look into the edits I made.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. Before, I didn't knew that `k` is a constant specified by the user. Now it makes more sense. Only that you try to minimize the intersection instead of maximizing the union seems strange to me given the testing background.

Comment: Minimizing the intersection of T or maximizing the union of T' is one and the same thing only, I guess.

Comment: I beg to differ. Consider a program with 300 lines and the test cases T1={1},  T2={2}, T3={1,...,200}, T4={1,...,100}∪{201,...,300} and k=2. If you minimize the intersection you have |T1∩T2|=0 but a coverage of <1%. If you maximize the union you have |T2∩T3|=100 but a coverage of 100%.

Comment: If you read correctly, it is mentioned above that T stores the line numbers which were not covered by the test case. It means ~T or T' contains the numbers which were covered/executed. Thus, Minimizing the intersection of T or maximizing the union of T' is one and the same thing

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. As you correctly guessed, I overlooked that T1 and so on contain the *un*covered lines. In your previous comment I also thought the `'` was a typo (therefore T=T') because T' was never mentioned before and using `'` to denote the complement of a set was unusual for me. Sorry for always questioning you. I know this can be really annoying.

Comment: It's alright, I should've mentioned it clearly in the question. As long as a solution to this problem comes forward, there is nothing that can be annoying. 